# ubuntu fault update manager

Tags: 12.04

When I install my program to the problems we encounter.

```
engmmrj@engmmrj-MS-7592:~$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install virtualboxReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-77 libbsd0 apache2.2-common linux-headers-generic
  linux-headers-3.5.0-18-generic linux-headers-3.5.0-18
  linux-headers-3.2.0-77-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 15.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe virtualbox amd64 4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.9 [15.6 MB]
Fetched 15.6 MB in 4min 27s (58.6 kB/s)                                        
(Reading database ... 293108 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace virtualbox 4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.9 (using .../virtualbox_4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.9_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement virtualbox ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up update-notifier-common (0.119ubuntu8.7) ...
flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20150414.1.orig.tar.gz
```

in line under stop install software

```
flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20150414.1.orig.tar.gz
```

what remove flashplugin in respoty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This step is apt to appear to sit idle as the updater is downloading a 25 MB file that contains the Adobe Flash plugin for ubuntu. At your current transfer speed (58.6kB/s), this takes about 8 minutes. You should wait and allow this to complete.

Alternatively, if you do not want the flash player, you can run `sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer`.

Additionally, you can tell the update manager to never update the package, by setting [a hold](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction_to_Holding_Packages):

```
sudo apt-mark hold flashplugin-installer
```

Note that in case of a hold, you will not receive security updates.